# How do I assign an argument to a string array?

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char username[256];
  username = ?;
}
```

thanks~

Comment: What if I pass 257 characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to make `username` be a pointer, then you can just assign it:

```
int
main(int argc, const char *const *argv)
{
    const char *username;
    if (argc >= 2)
        username = argv[1];
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s username ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

But if you really want to copy the contents of the array, you are looking for [`strncpy`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strncpy/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy another string (like argv[1]), then you probably want to use strncpy ( http://strncpy.org/ ). If you want to input it from stdin, then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fgets is probably a better bet.